# How to write a hash to work with a two parameter splat

Tags: ruby, selenium, teaspoon

I am trying to pass some additional options to a Selenium web driver for running JavaScript tests using Teaspoon.  I am unable to get it to recognize the `opts`.

My config code:

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 180 # 3 mins instead of the default 60 seconds
config.driver_options = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(client_driver: [:firefox, {http_client: client}])
```

Given the library code that uses my config options:

```
driver = ::Selenium::WebDriver.for(driver_options[:client_driver])
```

where the `::Selenium::WebDriver.for` function is defined as:

```
def self.for(*args)
  WebDriver::Driver.for(*args)
end
```

where `WebDriver::Driver.for` is defined as:

```
def for(browser, opts = {})
  listener = opts.delete(:listener)

  bridge = case browser
           when :firefox, :ff
             Firefox::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :remote
             Remote::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :ie, :internet_explorer
             IE::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :chrome
             Chrome::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :android
             Android::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :iphone
             IPhone::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :opera
             Opera::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :phantomjs
             PhantomJS::Bridge.new(opts)
           when :safari
             Safari::Bridge.new(opts)
           else
             raise ArgumentError, "unknown driver: #{browser.inspect}"
           end

  bridge = Support::EventFiringBridge.new(bridge, listener) if listener

  new(bridge)
end
```

How do I pass in a `(string, hash)` for `(browser, opts)`? With what I have tried, the whole hash `[:firefox, {http_client: client}]` gets passed into the `browser` variable.

Comment: `driver = ::Selenium::WebDriver.for(*driver_options[:client_driver])`?

Comment: that is library code. I can't easily change that :(

Comment: Wait, the definition of `for` and the invocation of `for` are both defined in the library?

Comment: yes, only place my code is is in the config file, where I set `config.driver_options `

Comment: Where is the library code? Can you change it? The fundamental problem here is the line: `Selenium::WebDriver.for(...)` only passing a single value, not a list.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on updating library code through a fork.  I was hoping there might be some syntax to avoid doing so.

Comment: What do you mean by `library`? Which library? Why can't you do what @ndn suggested `driver = ::Selenium::WebDriver.for(*driver_options[:client_driver])`

Comment: By library, I mean a github gem -- https://github.com/jejacks0n/teaspoon.  I have now forked it, but was hoping there is some syntax I could use when defining a has so that `::Selenium::WebDriver.for(driver_options[:client_driver])` would work without me having to update the library.

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do. Either the first library is broken or you are using it in ways it was not intended to be used.

Comment: Thanks @ndn.  That's what I wanted to know. I have a pull request to amend the gem.